# nsindexpath access to row to section property causes SIGABRT?

Tags: ios, nsindexpath

Targeting iOS 5.0 I see SIGABRT when I try to access row or section properties of NSIndexPath object in the following code:

```
NSIndexPath* path = [[NSIndexPath alloc] initWithIndex:0];
int row = path.row; //SIGABRT
int section = path.section;//SIGABRT
```

This example suggests using indexPathWithIndex: instead http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SourceView/Listings/BaseNode_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004441-BaseNode_m-DontLinkElementID_6

```
path = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:0];
```

The results remain consistent.  Does anyone have an explanation of why this might happen?  Is it that we just cannot operate on NSIndexPath in iOS 5.0?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating the index path using `indexPathForRow:inSection:`

```
NSIndexPath* path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
```

Comment: Thanks.  And sorry: I missed that note the first time through the class reference.  Any idea why they don't list this method under the class methods?

Comment: It's because these methods are defined as a category on NSIndexPath, not in the NSIndexPath class itself.  You can find the documentation here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can think of is to make sure you have `UIKit.framework` as one of your frameworks.  You can do this by pressing the plus button in the "Link Binary With Libraries" section under "Build Phases" on your target.  Also, make sure that you import `NSIndexPath.h` in the file you're trying to access the index path from.

I've run into this problem before, and this solved it.  That's because although `NSIndexPath` is universal between Cocoa and CocoaTouch, the Cocoa version doesn't have properties `row` and `section`.

If you already have `UIKit.framework`, try using `[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section]` instead of `[NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:index]`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that indexPathWithIndex: creates a one-node index path. Same for initWithIndex:. The section and row properties come from the UITableView category to the NSIndexPath class. A one-node index path is invalid for use with a table view because index paths passed to table views must contain two indices specifying the section and row (according to the error message I get when I run your code). The following code creates an index path with two indices and runs without throwing an NSInternalInconsistencyException:

```
NSUInteger x[] = {0 , 0};
NSIndexPath *path = [[NSIndexPath alloc] initWithIndexes: x length: 2];
int row = [path row];
int section = [path section];
row = path.row;
section = path.section;
```

Is this what you meant by "operate on NSIndexPath in iOS 5.0"?

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for your feedback.  I wasn't quite clear.  I meant operating on NSIndexPath instance data members.  'operating on an object' is fairly common in c++.  Is this not standard convention in obj-c?

Comment: "Operating on an object" isn't an expression I've heard in the context of Objective-C. (I don't recall hearing it in the context of C++, for that matter.) The expression that's unique to Objective-C is "sending an object a message," which means calling one of an object's instance methods.